# Projecting the unit cube onto a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry-of-numbers

I have some (rather exotic) subspace $L<R^n$, and I want to show that every non-zero vector in $\{0,1\}^n$ has a relatively small projection onto $L$. What general results and tools can be helpful? Anything from geometry of numbers?

Any suggestions appreciated!

---

Upon looking at the responses, some explanations may be in order. Let's say that a subspace $L<R^n$ is *oblique* if for any vector $z\in\{0,1\}^n$, the projection of $z$ onto $L$ is of length at most $\|z\|/\log\log n$ (say). What properties of a subspace can ensure that it is oblique? Can any general "obliqueness criteria" be given?

Comment: Please state a reasonable question and give background. As is, I vote to close.

Comment: I second Bill's vote. I don't care much about the background but a legitimate question should be far more precise than this. As of now, I do not even understand what "relatively small" might mean here. Indeed, no vector is longer than $\sqrt n$ and, unless your subspace is more or less aligned with some coordinate plane of small dimension, there is little chance to get much less for the maximal projection. 

Comment: @Bill: I believe, it is reasonable to request background for extremely specialized and artificially looking questions. This is certainly not the case with a general question like this. The question is motivated by my attempt to construct a graph with some particular property, but I am certainly not in a position to describe here all the work which led me to this question.

Comment: @fedja: I explained above what I mean by "relatively small". As to you last remark: if the subspace is aligned with some coordinate plane, then it most certainly does not have the property in question. Loosely speaking, what I need is a criterion to show that a subspace is *not* aligned with the coordinate planes!

Comment: I suggest re-editing or posting a new question with a description of the invariant subspace L and the clarification that you want the ratio.

Comment: @Aaron: I intentionally do not want to ask the question about a *specific* subspace. What if tomorrow I need another subspace? This is a general, and perfectly legitimate, question about the tools and results that can be useful to attack a special kind of problem.

I made it very clear now that I am looking at the ratio, and I am not going to post essentially the same question a second time. Instead, I would expect those who voted for closing to vote for re-opening now. I think it is absolutrely clear to everybody that my question is not "less real" than other MO questions.

Comment: I like the question. I never voted to close it but I did vote to reopen it as soon as it closed. I haven't seen more reopen votes since then.

Comment: I think the question has potential, but the discussion below Aaron Meyerowitz' answer makes a point: the question is not precise enough as it is.

Answer (score 1):

It *would* help  to know what $L$ is.

**update** This answer was for the question of how short the longest projection could be if $L$ is allowed to vary. There have since been some clarifications.

Here is an upper bound which I think I can prove to be the minimum among all the $d$ dimensional spaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with $n>d$ of course)

Let  $L$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of vectors whose first $d+1$ coordinates sum to $0$ and whose remaining coordinates are $0$. Project the vectors of  $\lbrace0,1\rbrace^n $ onto $L.$ The length of the longest projection is
$$\begin{cases} 
\sqrt{\frac{d+1}{4}},  & \mbox{if }d=2k+1 \\
\\
\sqrt{\frac{d+1-\frac{1}{d+1}}{4}}, & \mbox{if }d=2k. 
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks for an attempt to answer in essence - but I am afraid, I don't understood much here. For $d=1$ you seem to claim that the longest projection of a vector from `$\{0,1\}^n$` onto your subspace is $0$, do you? Anyway, I am speaking about some particular subspace, and I need the length of the projection normalized by dividing by the length of the vector itself.

Comment: Concerning "what $L$ actually is": is is an invariant subspace of a (high) tensor power of the "Fibonacci matrix" `$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$`. I am not asking, however, to look at my particular problem; rather, I am to trying to figure out what are possible approaches and useful tools.

Comment: OK, thanks, I think I fixed it. For $d=1$ the subspace spanned by $[1,-1,0,0,0,\cdots]$ sends some things to the zero vector and others to $[1/2,-1/2,0,0,0,\cdots]$. For $d=2$ some things go to $[2/3,-1/3,-1/3,0,0,0,\cdots]$. For $d=3$ some things go to $[1/2,1/2,-1/2,-1/2,0,0,\cdots]$.  

Comment: I see your point - but my question is not about the subspaces that you consider! I don't want all projections to be (relatively) small for any vector `$z\in\{0,1\}^n$` and any subspace $L$ - I have some particular subspace $L$ in mind, and I wonder what properties of this my subspace can guarantee that it is "not aligned with the vectors from `$\{0,1\}^n$`".

Comment: I am afraid there is still some misunderstanding here. Let's say that a subspace $L<R^n$ is *good* if for any `$z\in\{0,1\}^n$`, the projection of $z$ onto $L$ has length at most `$\|z\|/\log\log n$`. Good subspaces do exist: say, the one-dimensional subspace spanned by the vector $(1,1/\sqrt2,...,1/\sqrt n)$ is good. What I seek is a sufficiently general and versatile criterion for a subspace to be good.

Comment: OK I *think* that achieves its maximum ratio when it sends the all 1's vector $j$ to one of length roughly $\frac{\|j\|}{\sqrt{\log n}}.$ It would be better (but not optimal) to use $(1,1/\sqrt2,...,1/\sqrt {n/2},-1,-1/\sqrt2,...,-1/\sqrt {n/2}).$ None of the projections you care about are longer and many are shorter. Hence none of the ratios are larger.

Comment: You are right that this particular vector gives a slightly better constant, but I am not concerned much about improving the constant here. (The order of magnitude `$1/\sqrt{\log n}$` *is* best possible, by the way.) I just gave this as an example of a "good", or "oblique", subspace. More exotic subspaces are difficult to test directly, and so I am interested in some general criteria.

Comment: I just posted a question mathoverflow.net/questions/60775. If you can prove that $1/\sqrt{\log n}$ is best possible, that would be nice. I'd like to see *the* absolute best one-dimensional subspace.

Comment: Do not know what *the* absolute winner is - but as to $1/\sqrt{\log n}$, I have just posted an answer to your question...

Answer (score 0):

Look up Lindenstrauss-Johnson.

Comment: Lindenstrauss-Johnson says that there are subspaces which make the distance between the projections "close" to the distance between the original points. Here the desire is to have the projections be small so ideally one might want the projection to shrink distances as far as possible.

Comment: It is usually called the Johnson-Lindenstrauss Lemma.  :)

Comment: True, my apologies, although it has long transcended lemma-hood.

Comment: Not that I could see exactly how JL can help...